# What is the linguistic significance of dep and gov methods in Stanford NLP's Typed Dependency class?

Tags: nlp, dependency-grammar

I am looking at a [TypedDependency](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/TypedDependency.html) object like this: `root(ROOT-0, fired-4)`, which is part of the StanfordNLP suite.

If I call the object's .dep() method I get `fired/VBD`

If I call the object's .gov() method I get `ROOT`

These methods have cryptic names, which makes me think that maybe they refer to common linguistic concepts related to dependency parsing (that I don't know).

What do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extract is from [Stanford typed dependencies manual](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf):

> In the plain text format, a dependency is written as *abbreviated_relation_name*(governor, dependent) where the governor and the dependent are words in the sentence to which a number indicating the position of the word in the sentence is appended.

So, *dep* is the dependent word, and *gov* is the governor.